# Sphinx: link to original source file instead of copy

Tags: python-sphinx

I am currently using Sphinx for a private, local documentation consisting of `rst` and `md` files. It would be very handy to be able to jump from reading an html page directly to the original source file to make a quick adjustment.

By default, "View page source" links to a `txt` file copy of each file in `html/_sources/`. I would like to have a second link "edit source" that opens the original source file with the default program of the current OS. How could that be done?

Comment: What editor on what operating system? The question needs clarity in this detail, preferably including an example of the command you want to execute. Otherwise it also lacks focus because you are requesting 2 functionalities, one of them being vague and undefined.

Comment: @bad_coder I edited the question. I request one functionality: A new link "edit source" on every page, that opens the source file with the default program of the current OS.

Comment: You still don't specify what OS, the command that has to be constructed will be different. If it's Linux or Windows, because that incurs invalidating potential answers and folks searching will probably find this question being interested in the solution for another OS.

Comment: It should work on both Windows and Linux.